# struts 1.1 : dispatch action mistake : Error 400 no parameter in request

Tags: java, struts

In order to have multiple actions on one form, I use dispatchAction.
I'm starting with a lonely action which works when I use standard action with execute method. Before adding several action I start to convert this one.

At first load of the jsp, before any submit, I get the error :

Error 400: Request[/rechercheUtilisateur] does not contain handler parameter named hidden

Here is my configuration :

struts-config :

```
<action path="/rechercheUtilisateur" type="lan.poujoulat.osac.actions.RechercheUtilisateurAction" name="formRechercheUtilisateur" validate="true" input="/Administration/acces.jsp" scope="request" parameter="hidden">
    <forward name="réussiteRecherche" path="/Administration/acces.jsp">
    </forward>
```

jsp Administration/acces.jsp :

```
<SCRIPT>
   function setHidden(value){document.formRechercheUtilisateur.hidden.value=value;}
</SCRIPT>

<html:form action="/rechercheUtilisateur"
    name="formRechercheUtilisateur"
    type="lan.poujoulat.osac.forms.FormRechercheUtilisateur">
...
<td align="center" width="80"><a href="#"
    title='"Rechercher" />'> <input type=image
    value=submit src="./image/btnRech.gif" width="22" height="20"
    border="0" onclick="setHidden('recherche');"> </a></td> 
 </a>
...
          <html:hidden property="hidden" value="recherche"/>
</html:form>
```

RechercheUtilisateurAction.java :

```
public class RechercheUtilisateurAction extends DispatchAction
{

    public ActionForward recherche(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
```

I add the hidden property to my form :

```
public class FormRechercheUtilisateur extends ValidatorForm
{
...
    private String hidden = " ";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is in conflict with the `hidden` property of the form. The [JavaScript form object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javaform.html) has a `hidden` object that represents a hidden form field which is used for client server communications.

I am not sure that the following code:

```
function setHidden(value) {
  document.formRechercheUtilisateur.hidden.value=value;
}
```

will set the value of the hidden field you've setup with this:

```
<html:hidden property="hidden" value="recherche"/>
```

I've never used this object before so I can't really say.

The message is pretty clear, you don't get the parameter that `DispatchAction` needs on the request. The issue is simple to debug, see what parameters arrive on the request at the server. You could set the form method to GET for a quick look, just to see if the parameter is in the URL.

First check where the problem is (server side/client side), then the solution might be as simple as changing the name of the field (a name of "hidden" doesn't tell a thing of what it represents) or you could do something like:

```
function setHidden(value) {
  document.formRechercheUtilisateur.hidden.value=value;
  document.formRechercheUtilisateur.hidden.name='hidden';
}
```

but I am not sure if this will work though.

Comment: Indeed the name "hidden" was just because of the tu I follow to make this works. The real name is "method", once I have to put it in the CVS, but nvm. 

One of the right way to acceed to this variable is : this.form.method.value. And indeed the message was clear my parameter wasn't initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I program my index to pass in my action in order to initializee some data before my jsp. Index didn't provide hidden parameter so.

Solution : my jsp do not really need initialization (a null list doesn't provide problem in my display tag) so index action  forward is the Administration/acces.jsp. No need to execute the action implies no need to initialize my parameter.

And the initialization in the jsp is made by

this.form.hidden.value = value

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the real problem because the real problem was this code :

```
<forward name="acces" path="/rechercheUtilisateur.do">
```

Which I did not provide. Indeed this goes to

```
<action path="/rechercheUtilisateur" type="lan.poujoulat.osac.actions.RechercheUtilisateurAction" name="formRechercheUtilisateur" validate="true" input="/Administration/acces.jsp" scope="request" parameter="hidden">
    <forward name="réussiteRecherche" path="/Administration/acces.jsp">
    </forward>
```

with Hidden not initialized.

Solution :

```
 <forward name="acces" path="/acces.jsp">
```

Indeed I did not need initilisation before accessing to my jsp (the list in my display tag can be null)